# Angular material <mat-tab-group> is slow in internet explorer when clic the tab

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular-material2

I have a component where I have put angular material  and in each tab a component is loaded and it works well, both in chrome and in internet explorer 11. The problem is that in internet explorer it takes time to visualize the component of the tab I click on the tab. The components of the tabs are loaded all just load the main component, but internet explorer takes 1sec. in visualizing it when you just have to visualize it, it does nothing else.
My version of angular is 5 and the internet explorer is 11, and angular material is 2

This is my component where I have the tabs:

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="indicePestana" (selectedTabChange)="seleccionPestana($event)" [@.disabled]="true">
    <mat-tab label="Solicitud" itemid="Solicitud">
        <mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="indicePestanaSolicitud" (selectedTabChange)="seleccionPestanaSolicitud($event)">
            <mat-tab label="Datos Solicitud" itemid="Solicitud">
                <div class="contenido" style="margin-top:24px;">
                    <form [formGroup]="formularioSolicitud" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="lineaDivisoriaSolicitudes">
                            <span>Datos Solicitud</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fila-tabla" style="width:100%;">
                            <div class="campo-formulario ancho150">
                                <label for="txtNumeroSolicitud">Nº Solicitud</label>
                                <input type="text" id="txtNumeroSolicitud" name="txtNumeroSolicitud" #txtNumeroSolicitud class="cajaTextoFormulario cajaTextoSolicitudes negrita600 alignRight" formControlName="numeroSolicitud" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </mat-tab>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let fila of seccionesSolicitud">
        <mat-tab *ngIf="esTabActivo(fila)" label="{{fila.Descripcion}}">
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'laboratorio'">
                <app-laboratorio idSeccion="fila.IdSeccion" #appLaboratorio [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-laboratorio>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'manipuladoEncuadernacion'">
                <app-manipuladoenc [idSeccion]="fila.IdSeccion" #appManipuladoEnc [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-manipuladoenc>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'offset'">
                <app-offset [idSeccion]="fila.IdSeccion" #appOffset [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-offset>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'guillotinas'">
                <app-guillotina [idSeccion]="fila.IdSeccion" #appGuillotina [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-guillotina>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'copiadoras'">
                <app-copiadora [idSeccion]="fila.IdSeccion" #appCopiadoras [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-copiadora>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'composicion'">
                <app-composicion [idSeccion]="fila.IdSeccion" #appComposicion [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-composicion>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="fila.Codigo == 'paqueteriaDistribucion'">
                <app-paqueteriadist [idSeccion]="fila.IdSeccion" #appPaqueteriaDist [formularioSolicitud]="formularioSolicitud"></app-paqueteriadist>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-tab>
    </ng-container>
</mat-tab-group>
```

solicitud.component.ts: (the main component, it contains the tabs)

```
    import { Component, HostBinding, OnDestroy, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, NgModule, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewChecked, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Global } from '../../../shared/comun/global';
    //Componentes
    import { VentanaModalComponent } from '../../../shared/ventanaModal/ventanaModal.component';
    import { SolicitudesModelosAutocompleteComponent } from '../../../shared/forms/autocomplete/solicitudes/modelos/modelos.autocomplete.component';

    //Modelos:
    import { SeccionModel } from '../../../shared/models/solicitudes/seccion.model';
    import { PestanaActivaModel } from '../../../shared/models/solicitudes/comun.model';
    import { ConceptoModel } from '../../../shared/models/solicitudes/concepto.model';
    import { SolicitudModel } from '../../../shared/models/solicitudes/solicitud.model';

    import { SolicitudSeccionModel } from '../../../shared/models/solicitudes/solicitud.seccion.model';

    //Tipos Enum:
    import { TipoPestana } from '../../../shared/enums/solicitudes/tipoPestana.enum';
    import { TipoPestanaCodigo } from '../../../shared/enums/solicitudes/tipoPestana.enum';


    //Services:
    import { LoaderService } from '../../../shared/services/loader/loader.service';
    import { DialogService } from '../../../shared/services/dialog/dialog.service';
    import { VentanaModalConfig } from '../../../shared/ventanaModal/ventanaModal.config';
    import { VentanaModalRef } from '../../../shared/ventanaModal/VentanaModalRef';


    import { SolicitudComunService } from '../../../shared/services/solicitudes/comun/comun.service';
    import { SolicitudService } from '../../../shared/services/solicitudes/solicitud/solicitud.service';

    //import { ComunService } from '../../../shared/services/comun/comun.service';

    //Pipes:
    import { CurrencyPipe } from "../../../shared/pipes/pipeFormatCurrency/currency.pipe";
    import { IMyDpOptions, IMyDateModel, IMyDate, MyDatePicker, IMyInputFocusBlur } from 'mydatepicker';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


    //Directivas:
    import { FocusDirective } from '../../../shared/directives/focus.directive';




    import { CopiadoraComponent } from '../../copiadora/copiadora.component';
    import { GuillotinaComponent } from '../../guillotina/guillotina.component';
    import { LaboratorioComponent } from '../../laboratorio/laboratorio.component';
    import { ManipuladoEncComponent } from '../../manipuladoenc/manipuladoenc.component';
    import { OffsetComponent } from '../../offset/offset.component';
    import { PaqueteriaDistComponent } from '../../paqueteriadist/paqueteriadist.component';

    import { ComposicionComponent } from '../../composicion/composicion.component';

    //Inicio para performance tabs:
    import { TabsComponent } from '../../../shared/tabs/tabs.component';
    //Fin para performance tabs.

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-formulario-solicitud',
        templateUrl: './solicitud.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./solicitud.component.css'],
        providers: [CurrencyPipe],
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

    })

    export class FormularioSolicitudComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewChecked {
        public description: string;
        public closeFunction: Function;
        public modeloValidator = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }, [Validators.nullValidator]);
        public departamentoValidator = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }, [Validators.nullValidator]);
        public formularioSolicitud: FormGroup;
        private formularioRemesa: FormGroup;     
        private solicitudEditElement: SolicitudModel;

        onClickSeccion(event: any, data: SeccionModel) {

        }  
        @ViewChild('selectModelos') selectModelos: SolicitudesModelosAutocompleteComponent;
        @ViewChild(FocusDirective) focusDirective;
        @ViewChild('txtNumeroSolicitud') txtNumeroSolicitud;
        @ViewChild('appLaboratorio') laboratorioComponent: LaboratorioComponent;
        @ViewChild('appOffset') offsetComponent: OffsetComponent;
        @ViewChild('appGuillotina') guillotinaComponent: GuillotinaComponent;
        @ViewChild('appCopiadoras') copiadoraComponent: CopiadoraComponent;
        @ViewChild('appComposicion') composicionComponent: ComposicionComponent;
        @ViewChild('appManipuladoEnc') manipuladoEncComponent: ManipuladoEncComponent;  
        @ViewChild('appPaqueteriaDist') paqueteriaDistComponent: PaqueteriaDistComponent;   

        private seccionesSolicitud = new Array<SeccionModel>();
        private subCerrar: Subscription;
        private subElimpiar: Subscription;
        private subGuardar: Subscription;
        private subEliminar: Subscription;
        private fechaActual: Date = new Date(); 
        @Output() numeracionFicha: string;

        //Componentes:
        private subCargaComposicion: boolean;

        constructor(
            public config: VentanaModalConfig, public dialogVentanaModal2: VentanaModalRef, public ventanaModal: VentanaModalComponent,
            private elRef: ElementRef,           
            public dialog: DialogService,
            private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
            private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
            private _global: Global,
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private _loaderService: LoaderService,
            private _solicitudComunService: SolicitudComunService,
            private _solicitudService: SolicitudService,
            private loaderService: LoaderService) {
            this.description = 'Alta Solicitud';
            this._loaderService.globalVcRef = this.vcRef;
        }


        ngAfterContentInit() {
            setTimeout(() => this.focusDirective.setFocusInElement(this.txtNumeroSolicitud));
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this._solicitudComunService.getTareas();

            this.createFormSolicitud();
            this.inicializarFechaEntrada();
            this.createFormRemesa();
            //this.obtenerSecciones(); 
            this.addFichaConcepto();
        }


        ngOnDestroy() {
            if (this.subCerrar) { this.subCerrar.unsubscribe(); }
            if (this.subElimpiar) { this.subElimpiar.unsubscribe(); }
            if (this.subGuardar) { this.subGuardar.unsubscribe(); }
            if (this.subEliminar) { this.subEliminar.unsubscribe(); }
        }

        ngAfterViewInit() {
            if (this.config.data && this.config.data.editElement) {
                this.solicitudEditElement = this.config.data.editElement;            
                this.cargarFormularioSecciones();
                this.cargarFormularioSolicitud()

            } else {
                this.obtenerSecciones();
            }
            this.subCerrar = this.ventanaModal.onClose.subscribe(() => {
                console.log("suscrito");
            });
            this.subElimpiar = this.ventanaModal.onLimpiarEnModal.subscribe(() => {
                this.limpiar();
            });
            this.subGuardar = this.ventanaModal.onGuardarEnModal.subscribe(() => {
                this.guardar();
            });
            this.subEliminar = this.ventanaModal.onEliminarEnModal.subscribe(() => {
                this.eliminar();
            });
        }


        trackById(index, item: SeccionModel) {
            return item.IdSeccion;
        }

        guardar() {
            let solicitud: SolicitudModel;     
            if (this.validarSecciones()) {     
                solicitud = this.componerSolicitud();
                //remesa = this.componerRemesa();
                solicitud.SolicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccionesSolicitud();     
                if (solicitud) {
                    let esValidoFormSolicitud: boolean  = this.validarFormularioSeccion(this.formularioSolicitud, TipoPestana.Solicitud);              
                    if (esValidoFormSolicitud) {
                        this.insertarSolicitud(solicitud);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        insertarSolicitud(solicitud: SolicitudModel) {
            this._solicitudService.insertarSolicitud(solicitud).then(retSol => {
                if (retSol) {
                    let sol:SolicitudModel = retSol;
                    this.formularioSolicitud.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(sol.NumeroSolicitud);
                    this.establecerNumeroSolicitudEnSecciones(sol);              
                }
            });
        }

        componerSolicitud(): SolicitudModel {
            let solicitud: SolicitudModel;
            let form: FormGroup = this.formularioSolicitud;
            solicitud = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioSolicitud(form);
            return solicitud;
        }
        componerFormularioSeccionesSolicitud(sol: SolicitudModel) {
            if (this.laboratorioComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.laboratorioComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.Laboratorio);
            }

            if (this.manipuladoEncComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.manipuladoEncComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.ManipuladoEnc);
            }

            if (this.offsetComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.offsetComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.Offset);     
            }

            if (this.guillotinaComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.guillotinaComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.Guillotinas);     
            }

            if (this.copiadoraComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.copiadoraComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.Copiadoras);
            } 

            if (this.composicionComponent) {          
                let form: FormGroup = this.composicionComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.Composicion);          
            }

            if (this.paqueteriaDistComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.paqueteriaDistComponent.formulario;
                this.componerFormularioSeccion(form, sol, TipoPestana.PaqueteriaDist);
            } 
        }

        componerObjetoSeccionesSolicitud(): Array<SolicitudSeccionModel> {
            let solicitud: SolicitudModel;
            let solicitudSeccion: SolicitudSeccionModel;
            let listaSolicitudSeccion: SolicitudSeccionModel[]
            if (this.laboratorioComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.laboratorioComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Laboratorio);
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }

            if (this.offsetComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.offsetComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Offset);
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }
            if (this.guillotinaComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.guillotinaComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Guillotinas);        
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }

            if (this.copiadoraComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.copiadoraComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Copiadoras);
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }

            if (this.composicionComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.composicionComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Composicion);
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }

            if (this.manipuladoEncComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.manipuladoEncComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.ManipuladoEnc);
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }

            if (this.paqueteriaDistComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.paqueteriaDistComponent.formulario;
                solicitudSeccion = this.componerObjetoSeccion(form, TipoPestana.PaqueteriaDist);
                if (!listaSolicitudSeccion) listaSolicitudSeccion = new Array<SolicitudSeccionModel>();
                listaSolicitudSeccion.push(solicitudSeccion);
            }       
            return listaSolicitudSeccion;       
        }
        establecerNumeroSolicitudEnSecciones(retSol:SolicitudModel) {   
            if (this.laboratorioComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.laboratorioComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }
            if (this.offsetComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.offsetComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }
            if (this.guillotinaComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.guillotinaComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }

            if (this.copiadoraComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.copiadoraComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }

            if (this.composicionComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.composicionComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }   

            if (this.manipuladoEncComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.manipuladoEncComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }          

            if (this.paqueteriaDistComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.paqueteriaDistComponent.formulario;
                form.get("numeroSolicitud").setValue(retSol.NumeroSolicitud);
            }
        }


        validarSecciones(): boolean {
            let validacionComponent: boolean = true;

            if (this.laboratorioComponent && validacionComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.laboratorioComponent.formulario;
                validacionComponent = this.validarFormularioSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Laboratorio);
            }

            if (this.offsetComponent && validacionComponent) {
                let form: FormGroup = this.offsetComponent.formulario;
                validacionComponent = this.validarFormularioSeccion(form, TipoPestana.Offset);
            }



            return validacionComponent;
        }
        validarFormularioSeccion(form: FormGroup, tipoPestana: string) {
            let pestanaActiva: PestanaActivaModel = this._solicitudComunService.getPestanaActiva();
            let resp: boolean = this._solicitudComunService.validateAllFormFields(form);
            if (!resp) {
                if (pestanaActiva.NombrePestana != tipoPestana) {
                    this._solicitudComunService.openDialog("La solicitud no se pudo guardar. Revise los campos de la ficha de " + tipoPestana, 'Guardar Solicitud');
                }
            }
            return resp;
        }
        componerFormularioSeccion(form: FormGroup, sol: SolicitudModel, tipoPestana: string) {
            let solSecc: SolicitudSeccionModel;   
            switch (tipoPestana) {      
                case TipoPestana.Laboratorio:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Laboratorio);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioLaboratorio(form, solSecc, sol);
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.ManipuladoEnc:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.ManipuladoEnc);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioManipuladoEnc(form, solSecc, sol);
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.Offset:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Offset);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioOffset(form, solSecc, sol);
                    break;
                case TipoPestana.Guillotinas:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Guillotinas);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioGuillotinas(form, solSecc, sol);
                    break;               
                case TipoPestana.Copiadoras:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Copiadoras);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioCopiadoras(form, solSecc, sol);
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.Composicion:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Composicion);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioComposicion(form, solSecc, sol);            
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.PaqueteriaDist:
                    solSecc = sol.SolicitudSeccion.find(sec => sec.Seccion.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.PaqueteriaDist);
                    this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioPaqueteriaDist(form, solSecc, sol);
                    break;
            }
            if (solSecc && solSecc.SolicitudSeccionMaterial && solSecc.SolicitudSeccionMaterial.length > 0) {                
                setTimeout(() => {                      this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioSolicitudSeccionMaterial(form, solSecc.SolicitudSeccionMaterial);                  
                });
            }
            if (solSecc && solSecc.SolicitudSeccionTarea && solSecc.SolicitudSeccionTarea.length > 0) {
                setTimeout(() => { this._solicitudComunService.componerFormularioSolicitudSeccionTarea(form, solSecc.SolicitudSeccionTarea); });
            }
        }
        componerObjetoSeccion(form: FormGroup, tipoPestana: string): SolicitudSeccionModel {
            let solicitudSeccionModel: SolicitudSeccionModel;
            switch (tipoPestana) {
                case TipoPestana.Guillotinas:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioGuillotina(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Guillotinas).IdSeccion;
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.Laboratorio:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioLaboratorio(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Laboratorio).IdSeccion;            
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.Offset:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioOffset(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Offset).IdSeccion;
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.Composicion:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioComposicion(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Composicion).IdSeccion;
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.Copiadoras:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioCopiadora(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.Copiadoras).IdSeccion;
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.ManipuladoEnc:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioManipuladoEnc(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.ManipuladoEnc).IdSeccion;
                    break;

                case TipoPestana.PaqueteriaDist:
                    solicitudSeccionModel = this._solicitudComunService.componerModelFormularioPaqueteriaDist(form);
                    solicitudSeccionModel.IdSeccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(sec => sec.Codigo == TipoPestanaCodigo.PaqueteriaDist).IdSeccion;
                    break;
            }
            return solicitudSeccionModel;
        }

        limpiar() {
            let pestanaActiva: PestanaActivaModel = this._solicitudComunService.getPestanaActiva();
            if (pestanaActiva.NombrePestana == TipoPestana.Solicitud) {

            }
        }
        eliminar() {
            let pestanaActiva: PestanaActivaModel = this._solicitudComunService.getPestanaActiva();
            if (pestanaActiva.NombrePestana == TipoPestana.Solicitud) {

            }
        }
        seleccionPestana(event: any) {
            console.log('seleccionPestana: ' + event)
            //establecemos la pestaña activa:
            this._solicitudComunService.setPestanaActiva(event.tab);    
        }
        seleccionPestanaSolicitud(event: any) {
            console.log('seleccionPestanaSolicitud: ' + event);
            //establecemos la pestaña activa:

        } 
        opcionesFecha: IMyDpOptions = {
            inline: false,
            disableUntil: { year: 0, month: 0, day: 0 },
            disableDays: [{ year: 0, month: 0, day: 0 }],
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            showWeekNumbers: false,
            selectorHeight: '232px',
            selectorWidth: '252px'
        }

        obtenerSecciones() {
            this._solicitudComunService.ObtenerSecciones().then(secciones => {
                let sc: SeccionModel[] = secciones as SeccionModel[];
                this.seccionesSolicitud = sc;
            });
        }
        cargarFormularioSecciones() {
            this._solicitudComunService.ObtenerSecciones().then(secciones => {
                let sc: SeccionModel[] = secciones as SeccionModel[];
                this.seccionesSolicitud = sc;
                if (this.solicitudEditElement && this.solicitudEditElement.SolicitudSeccion && this.solicitudEditElement.SolicitudSeccion.length > 0) {
                    for (let i: number = 0; i <= this.solicitudEditElement.SolicitudSeccion.length - 1; i++) {
                        let seccion: SeccionModel;
                        seccion = this.seccionesSolicitud.find(c => c.IdSeccion == this.solicitudEditElement.SolicitudSeccion[i].IdSeccion);                 
                        //*Inicio para performance tabs.
                        //this.incluirFicha(seccion);
                        //Fin para performance tabs.
                        seccion.Activo = true;
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(() => { this.componerFormularioSeccionesSolicitud(this.solicitudEditElement)});  
            });
        }
        cargarFormularioSolicitud() {
            let sol: SolicitudModel = this.solicitudEditElement;
            let form: FormGroup = this.formularioSolicitud;       
            form.controls['numeroSolicitud'].setValue(sol.NumeroSolicitud);  
        }
        inicializarFechaEntrada() {     
            //Fecha fin periodo por defecto
            let fechaInicioPorDefecto: any = {
                date: { year: this.fechaActual.getFullYear(), month: this.fechaActual.getMonth() + 1, day: this.fechaActual.getDate() },
                formatted: "",
                epoc: 0 
            };
            this.formularioSolicitud.get('grupoFechas').get("fechaInicio").setValue(fechaInicioPorDefecto);
        }
        createFormSolicitud() {
            var validatorArr = [];
            validatorArr.push(this._solicitudComunService.validarPeriodos.bind(this, "fechaInicio|Fecha Inicio", "fechaFin| Fecha Fin"));     
            this.formularioSolicitud = this.formBuilder.group({
                numeroSolicitud: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.nullValidator]),          
            });
        }




        esTabActivo(seccion:SeccionModel) {
            if (seccion && seccion.Activo) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        onCloseLink() {
            this.closeFunction();
        }



        private onSelectItemModelo(obj: any) {
            if (obj && obj.item) {
                this.formularioSolicitud.get("idModeloSel").setValue(obj.item.IdModelo);
            }
        }

        private onSelectItemDepartamento(obj: any) {
            if (obj && obj.item) {
                this.formularioSolicitud.get("idDepartamentoSel").setValue(obj.item.IdModelo);
            }
        }

        createFormRemesa() {
            this.formularioRemesa = this.formBuilder.group({
                numeroSolicitud: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.nullValidator]),
                boletin: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.nullValidator]),
                fechaFin: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: false }, [Validators.nullValidator]),
                numEstadistico: new FormControl(null, [Validators.nullValidator]),
                paquetes: new FormControl(null, [Validators.nullValidator]),
                conceptosArray: this.formBuilder.array([]),
            });
        }


        clickAddConcepto() {
            this.addFichaConcepto();
        }

        addFichaConcepto(concepto?: ConceptoModel) {
            let conceptosArray = <FormArray>this.formularioRemesa.controls['conceptosArray'];
            let addrCtrl = this.initConcepto(concepto);
            conceptosArray.push(addrCtrl);
        }


        initConcepto(concepto?: ConceptoModel) {
            if (!concepto) {
                return this.formBuilder.group({
                    cantidadEnviada: [this._global.transform("0", 0), Validators.nullValidator],
                    cantidadSolicitada: [this._global.transform("0", 0), Validators.nullValidator],
                    descripcion: [null, Validators.nullValidator],
                });
            }
        }
        onClickEliminarConcepto(event: any, i: number) {
            const control = <FormArray>this.formularioRemesa.controls['conceptosArray'];
            control.removeAt(i);
        }
        onBlurCantidadSolicitadaConcepto(event: any, i: number) {
        }

        onBlurCantidadEnviadaConcepto(event: any, i: number) {

        }

        ngAfterViewChecked() {
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        }



    }
```

I don't understand why it takes to display the component from internet explorer 11, it takes about 1 second, when you simply have to show it.
The fact is that if I try to add a single tab, internet explorer is not slow if I add another, it goes a little slower and so on

¿Any idea?

Comment: Try to clear the IE browser cache and cookie, then, recheck whether it's better. Besides, you could try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether it will send request and do any action when click the tab. And you could also check the JavaScript code and the CSS style, whether they will cause this issue. If still not found the solution, try to post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried all those cases without succes, in fact I even removed the component of angular material <mat-tab-group> and created one myself, without styles, and it was still taking the same